# How do I graphically compare the prices of 2 products from dataframe that include prices and products?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

#### >>>products_name >>> price

1. ASUS Chromebook C202SA-YS02     **$199.00**
2. ASUS C302CA-DHM4 Chromebook     **$469.58**
3. ASUS VivoBook E203MA     **$199.00**
4. ASUS ZenBook 13     **$799.99**
5. ASUS Chromebook C523NA-DH02     **$255.99**
6. ASUS VivoBook S     **$648.99**

How do I graphically compare the prices of any two row(for ex: 2.row and 5.row)?

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=product_name, y=price))
```

Comment: Basically you want to compare two numbers. How exactly do you wish to graphically compare them? A two column histogram?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: `+ geom_bar()' ?

Comment: Error: Don't know how to add "geom_bar()" to a plot

Comment: i think we need a few parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `a` is your dataframe, this will draw an histogram - actually a bar chart, to use the correct term as pointed out in the comments - with all the "rows" of your dataframe, you have hence an bar chart with a bar for each dataframe row.

```
ggplot(data=a, aes(x=product_name, y=price)) + geom_bar(stat="identity"))
```

If you want only two bars in the bar chart, for example the ones corresponding to rows 2 and 5, you can do:

```
ggplot(data=a[c(2, 5),], aes(x=product_name, y=price)) + geom_bar(stat="identity"))
```

Remember to include the ggplot2 library by calling `library(ggplot2)` before drawing the histogram.

Comment: A histogram is a plot of a continuous distribution broken into bins. This is a bar chart.